# Get_template_part inside filter?

Tags: filters, gallery

Is it possible to remove gallery from content but in its place do  `get_template_part('content-gallery');` ?

I have this piece of code which removes gallery from post but I am inserting content-gallery.php which grabs and formats gallery the way I wanted to. This works nice but gallery is inserted at the end of the post what is the problem, it needs to be inserted in whatever position it is in post. I just want a quick fix.

functions.php - removes gallery

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_gallery');
function remove_gallery($content) {
  preg_match_all( '/'. get_shortcode_regex() .'/s', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
  if ( ! empty( $matches ) ) {
    foreach ( $matches as $shortcode ) {
      if ( 'gallery' === $shortcode[2] ) {
        $pos = strpos( $content, $shortcode[0] );
        if ($pos !== false)
          return substr_replace( $content, '', $pos, strlen($shortcode[0]) );
      }
    }
  }
  return $content;
}
```

content-gallery.php - manual gallery - call images and format them easily

```
$gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
$gallery_attachment_ids = explode( ',', $gallery['ids'] );

$img_attribs = wp_get_attachment_image_src($gallery_attachment_ids[0], 'gallery_main' ); // returns an array
if( $img_attribs ) :

    foreach($gallery_attachment_ids as $id) :  
        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'gallery_thumb' ); 
    $img_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'gallery_main' ); 
    $img_alt = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); 
    ?>
    <div class="item">
        <img class="thumb img-responsive" data-url="<?php echo $img_full[0]; ?>" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img_alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $img_alt; ?>" />
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is in `page.php` (I would need to remove manual calling for `get_template_part()` and call it inside filter function.

```
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php  get_template_part('content-gallery'); ?>
```

EDIT

Full filter function

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_gallery');
function remove_gallery($content) {
  preg_match_all( '/'. get_shortcode_regex() .'/s', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
  if ( ! empty( $matches ) ) {
    foreach ( $matches as $shortcode ) {
      if ( 'gallery' === $shortcode[2] ) {
        $pos = strpos( $content, $shortcode[0] );


        if ($pos !== false) {
          ob_start; 
          get_template_part('content-gallery.php');
          $contentgallery = ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
          return substr_replace( $content, $contentgallery, $pos, strlen($shortcode[0]) );
        }


      }
    }
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: `get_gemplate_part()` is a function that echoes its output. It doesn't return any variable you can process within a search and replace logic. That's why you can't use it inside a filter that way without output buffering, which is not very performant. I would advice you to rethink the whole approach. Can't you use the [`post_gallery`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_gallery) filter to apply your html instead of loading an external template? It seems more reusable and not theme dependant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use output buffering to get the template output and return it in place of the emptied shortcode content:

```
if ($pos !== false)
    ob_start; 
    get_template_part('content-gallery.php');
    $contentgallery = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return substr_replace( $content, $contentgallery, $pos, strlen($shortcode[0]) );` 
}
```

**EDIT** It might make it easier to just replace the gallery shortcode?

```
remove_shortcode('gallery');
add_shortcode('gallery','my_content_gallery');
function my_content_gallery() {
    ob_start; 
    get_template_part('content-gallery.php');
    $contentgallery = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $contentgallery;
}
```

Comment: Hm it doesn't work, I get a first half of content echoed wierdly all the way at the top of the page, gallery is missing and second half (after gallery) is displaying at  usual (correct) position. The full code of filter I am using is in edited post

Comment: seems like a complex way of doing it, I'd recommend just replacing the gallery shortcode (see edit)